# Confused on Reading SharedPreferences Without a PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Because I want an `AppCompat` Action Bar on all of my settings submenus, I had to implement a workaround and my Settings Activity extends `AppCompatActivity`, not `PreferenceActivity`. I'm using a `PreferenceFragment` in the activity to handle the preferences, and each `PreferenceScreen` has its own xml file, which the PreferenceFragment switches out for each submenu in the settings. All of this was necessary to get the Action Bar to stay put through all of my submenus.

I'm trying to read a string value from the shared preferences file from within my MainActivity, and I've tried three different methods for getting that information, none of which have worked:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String btSelectPref = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.bt_select_key), "");
```

,

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
String btSelectPref = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.bt_select_key), "");
```

and

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String btSelectPref = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.bt_select_key), "");
```

Here is the relevant section of my preferences.xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Bluetooth"
    android:key="pref_bt">
    <Preference
        android:title="Select Bluetooth Device"
        android:key="@string/bt_select_key"
        android:defaultValue="0">
    </Preference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

This should fill the `btSelectPref` string with a "0", but it's always empty when I test it. I have included `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);` in onCreate in my MainActivity, so the default values should be set.

I'm not sure which of these methods I should be using since I have multiple resource files for my settings, but none of them seem to be working for me. In the case of `getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE)`, I have no idea what the name parameter should be referencing, since I've never named my shared preferences file.

**EDIT: It turns out my issue was not related to getting values from the shared preferences file.** I just had the wrong xml tag on the preference I was trying to check the value of. I changed it from a generic `<Preference>` tag to a `<ListPreference>` and my code started working with `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I have used AppCompat for my preference screen too.I did this because I wanted to use Vintage Chroma and this was the only way. But I am able to use PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference() without any errors.

**Also if you want to use default shared preferences in the Fragment you can use :**

`SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Here is my full code :

public class PreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new PreferencesScreen())
            .commit();

    ActionBar toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PreferencesScreen extends PreferenceFragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_xml);
    }
}
```

}

**Here is my code snippet for MAinActivity**

Just the initial part where I set the default text theme.

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

```
AutoCompleteTextView mytextview;
public static String[] list;
ArrayList<String> recent = new ArrayList<String>();
public int recent_index = 0;
Menu mMenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /*Setting default theme.*/

    SharedPreferences Sp= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int firstRun=Sp.getInt("firstRun",0);
    if(firstRun==0)
    {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=Sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("paragraphFontColor", Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    editor.putInt("headingFontColor",Color.parseColor("#DE5246"));
    editor.putInt("subheadingFontColor",Color.parseColor("#597d5e"));
    editor.putInt("hyperlinksFontColor",Color.parseColor("#A5D8F5"));
    editor.putInt("bodyColor",Color.parseColor("#2b2b2b"));
    editor.putString("paragraphFont","PrintClearly.otf");
    editor.putString("headingFont","PrintBold.otf");
    editor.putString("subheadingFont","PrintBold.otf");
    editor.putString("hyperlinkFont","PrintBold.otf");
    editor.putString("paragraphFontStyle","normal");
    editor.putString("headingFontStyle","normal");
    editor.putString("subheadingFontStyle","normal");
    editor.putString("hyperlinkFontStyle","normal");
    editor.putString("actionBarColor","#597d5e");
    editor.putString("paragraphFontSize","20px");
    editor.putString("headingFontSize","30px");
    editor.putString("subheadingFontSize","20px");
    editor.putString("hyperlinkFontSize","20px");
    editor.putString("firstRun",0);
    editor.commit();
  }
```

`

Comment: I'm a little confused by your code. Why did you create those SharedPreferences objects in PreferencesActivity and PreferencesScreen if you don't actually use them?

I have no SharedPreferences declared in my Settings Activity or Settings Fragment, because I only need to access the values in the shared preferences file from my MainActivity. Am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: You are **not** going the wrong way.I just put it there to show that Default Shared Preference can be accessed in the preference activity as well as the fragment.I will remove it. I only access the Shared preference from MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that yours worked and mine didn't led me to look elsewhere, and I _think_ my problem was actually in the fact that I was using a placeholder `<Preference>` in my preference.xml. I changed it to a `<ListPreference>` and I was able to use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

This question is a bit pointless now since my actual issue was so far removed from what I was asking about, but thanks again for the help in diagnosing.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do and what you are doing differs. If you just want to put default shared preference for a key then **consider this example**. If your whole activity has just one shared pref file then you need not specify any name. It will automatically get it.

```
public MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    int test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);

        mPrefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        test = mPrefs.getInt("pref_bt_select", 0);}
}
```

For the above example you can define the key and default value in your strings.xml and then you can refer to it while looking for the prefs you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm actually not sure if I have more than one shared preferences file. Does each xml file with a `PreferenceScreen` as the root element get its own shared preferences file, or will they be grouped together into one by default?

My implementation has my `PreferenceFragment` switching out the xml file it uses for each submenu in the settings, so I have 3 xml files for preferences total (one main settings menu and two submenus).

I tried using `getPreferences()` in place of `getSharedPreferences()`, but I'm still getting the same result.